# comma-separate list of expressions for self and following siblings works in XPath but not as XSLT match pattern

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is a valid XPath 2.0:

```
//hi[@rend="bold"]/(self::hi, following-sibling::*, following-sibling::text())
```

It select all the hi nodes with the given attribute as well as all the sibling element and text nodes.

If, however, I try to use this XPath in XSLT 2.0 like this:

```
<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='bold']/(self::hi, following-sibling::*, following-sibling::text())">
        <!--do something-->
    </xsl:template>
```

I am getting a syntax error. Why is that? How can I rewrite this matching pattern so that it works in XSLT?

The goal is to be able to wrap all of the above in a new element.

All best,
Tench

Comment: "The goal is to be able to wrap all of the above in a new element." sounds as if an `<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="hi[@rend = 'bold']"><wrap><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></wrap></xsl:for-each-group>` might be a different approach in XSLT 2.0 to solve the problem. But it is hard to tell without seeing the input XML and the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve the above:

```
  <xsl:template match="hi[@rend='bold']">
        <xsl:element name="wrap">
        <xsl:element name="hi">
            <xsl:attribute name="rend">bold</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::node()"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[preceding-sibling::hi[@rend='bold']]"></xsl:template>
```

Basically, we match the hi element first, wrap it and copy its following nodes; and in a separate pattern, we match the nodes that have the particular hi element as their preceding sibling so that their content does not appear twice in the output.

An important lesson learned: you can't just take any xPath and stick it in your XSLT.

Comment: It seems to me the contents of your 1st template could be simplified to `<wrap><xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::node()"/></wrap>`.

Answer (score 2):

I've sometimes been in the position where I want to apply a template rule to nodes selected by a complex pattern like this, and the best solution has been to bind a global variable to all the relevant nodes and then use the global variable in the pattern:

```
<xsl:variable name="afterBold"
  select="//hi[@rend="bold"]/
   (self::hi, following-sibling::*, following-sibling::text())"/>

<xsl:template match="node()[. intersect $afterBold]"/>
```

The above requires XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 3.0 it can be simplified:

```
<xsl:template match="$afterBold"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a syntax error. Why is that?

An XSLT *match pattern* has [syntax rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-syntax) of its own. Only a subset of valid XPath expressions are also valid match patterns.

> How can I rewrite this matching pattern so that it works in XSLT?

Off the top of my head:

```
<xsl:template match="hi[@rend='bold'] | *[preceding-sibling::hi[@rend='bold']] | text()[preceding-sibling::hi[@rend='bold']]">
```

There may be a more elegant way to express it, but I believe it does what you said you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This didn't work for me probably because I still needed to have all of those taken together in order to wrap them in one element. I'm not really sure. But thanks anyway. I managed to find a solution and I posted it here.

Comment: "*... needed to have all of those taken together in order to wrap them in one element.*" Well, then it wouldn't have worked for you even if your original attempt were a valid match pattern. I sort of suspected this - that's why I said "*I believe it does what you said you wanted to do*".